# Parsing JSON Object in jQuery and create drop downs

Tags: jquery, json

I want to parse a JSON object and create drop downs out of it. There will be six drop downs -

productType
reportNames
startDate
startMonth
endDate
endMonth

I am able to create the first drop down 'productType' but when I am trying to create others it shows me 
some Undefined error message.

Here is my code -

### HTML

```
  <select id="product_type"></select>
  <select id="report_type"></select>
  <select id="startDate"></select>
  <select id="startMonth"></select>
  <select id="endDate"></select>
  <select id="endMonth"></select>
```

### Javascript

```
  var jsonString = '[{"productType": "ABC","reportNames": ["Report1",{"startDate": ["2010","2011"],"startMonth": ["May","June"],"endDate":["2010","2011"],"endMonth": ["May","June"]},"Report 2",{"startDate": ["2010","2011"],"startMonth": ["May","June"],"endDate": ["2010","2011"],"endMonth": ["May","June"]}]},{"productType": "XYZ","reportNames": ["Report 3",{"startDate": ["2010","2011"],"startMonth": ["May","June"],"endDate": ["2010","2011"],"endMonth": ["May","June"] },"Report 4",{"startDate": ["2010","2011"], "startMonth": ["May", "June" ],"endDate": ["2010","2011"],"endMonth": ["May","June"]}]}]';



  var myData = JSON.parse(jsonString);

  var $product_type = $('#product_type');
  var $report_type = $('#report_type');

  $.each(myData, function () {
      $('<option>' + this.productType + '</option>').appendTo($product_type);
  });

  $.each(myData, function () {
      $('<option>' + this.productType[0].reportNames +   '</option>').appendTo($report_type);
```

});

---

Basically I want to create six drop downs like this:

productType - ABC, XYZ

reportNames - Report1, Report2

startDate - 2010, 2011

startMonth - May, June

endDate - 2010, 2011

endMonth - May, June

I am using jQuery to parse the JSON object.
Here is the demo - http://jsfiddle.net/Lnv9d/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are accessing your JSON incorrectly for the second dropdown.

`this.productType` is a string, not an array, so you cannot call `this.productType[0].reportNames`

If you change it to `this.reportNames[0]` then you may just get what you are looking for.

[Here is the updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnv9d/2/)

Edit: [Here is a new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnv9d/7/) which handles showing and hiding the options based on what is already selected. It could probably use some optimization, but it works.

Comment: That I have already done. Now I want to show the two reportNames under the productType ABC. Modified your demo a bit. So it should come Report1 and Report2 in the drop down. http://jsfiddle.net/Lnv9d/3/

Comment: This doesn't seems to be right since 'COUNTER Journal Report 2' and 'COUNTER Journal Report 4' don't appear in the second box.

Comment: Report1, Report2 are part of productType ABC and Report 3, Report 4 are part of productType XYZ. Can't we create a dropdown for Report1 and Report2 as the parent node is the same.

Comment: To get the end result you are looking for you are going to have to take one of two paths: 1) populate every possible member in the appropriate select, then listen for a `change` event which will show/hide the members that are/aren't acceptable. 2) Only ever have the top-level select loaded, and on changing the selected option empty and repopulate each select which relies on the top-level one.

Comment: @winterblood I have modified the question. Does it make sense now? Could you please help me in creating the drop downs for the path 1 which you have mentioned

Comment: @user2080056 I'm working on a basic fiddle now, give me a few minutes.

Comment: Hi guys, I will also suggest to modify the JSON string if possible. I belive that a better structure is possible and will make it simpler to work with.

Comment: @Joqus I agree a better JSON structure would make things a bit easier, but what is there can be worked around.

Comment: @winterblood Yes it can, but if it is himself that is creating the JSON it would be clever to rearrange it.

Comment: @Joqus Do you have any idea like how I can modify this JSON so that it can simplify the whole process.

Comment: Could you please help me create a better and organized JSON out of this that will simplify the whole process.

Comment: Instead of `["Report1",{"startDate": ["2010","2011"],"startMonth"...` I would put an atribute name inside this object: `[{"name": "Report1" "startDate": ["2010","2011"],"startMonth"...` . This way you have an object that represents the whole report info and you can loop this array and get the `name` property (or the one you want).

Comment: I guess you should try it for yourself. Also I guess this will be helpfull: [link](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: I haven't implemented the JSON changes, but here is [a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnv9d/7/). It's not the greatest piece of code around, it could be cleaner, it could do with some optimization, but it works and it's time for me to leave work now.

Comment: @winterblood you are awesome. You even wrote the onchange functions. I really appreciate your effort. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
$.each(myData, function () {
   $('<option>' + this.productType[0].reportNames + '</option>').appendTo($report_type);
});
```

to:

```
$.each(myData, function () {
   $('<option>' + this.reportNames[0] + '</option>').appendTo($report_type);
});
```

Comment: That I have already done. Now I want to show the two reportNames under the productType ABC. So it should come Report1 and Report2 in the drop down. jsfiddle.net/Lnv9d/3

Comment: There will be six drop downs:
productType - ABC, XYZ

reportNames - Report1, Report2

startDate - 2010, 2011
startMonth - May, June
endDate - 2010, 2011
endMonth - May, June

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.   Please always explain how your solution works and why it is a good idea for the benefit of future researchers.

Answer (score 1):

```
You don't need to run the loop again for every select box.

You can try this , you will get the same result.

var myData = JSON.parse(jsonString);
var $product_type = $('#product_type');
var $report_type = $('#report_type');
var $start_date = $('#startDate');
var $start_month = $('#startMonth');
var $end_date = $('#endDate');
var $end_month = $('#endMonth');

var counter = 0; 
$.each(myData, function () {
    $('<option>' + this.productType + '</option>').appendTo($product_type);

    $('<option>' + this.reportNames[1].startDate[counter] + '</option>').appendTo($start_date);

    $('<option>' + this.reportNames[0] + '</option>').appendTo($report_type);

    $('<option>' + this.reportNames[1].startMonth[counter] + '</option>').appendTo($start_month);

    $('<option>' + this.reportNames[1].endDate[counter] + '</option>').appendTo($end_date);

    $('<option>' + this.reportNames[1].endMonth[counter] + '</option>').appendTo($end_month);

    counter++;
});
```

Comment: In the second dropdown it's showing Report1 and Report3. But I want to show Report1 and Report2 as both these are part of the node productType ABC. Report 3 is part of the node XYZ.

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.   Please always explain how your solution works and why it is a good idea for the benefit of future researchers.

Answer (score 1):

```
This is the updated one


var counter = 0; 
var reportCounter = 0;
$.each(myData, function () {

    $('<option>' + this.productType + '</option>').appendTo($product_type);

    $('<option>' + this.reportNames[1].startDate[counter] + '</option>').appendTo($start_date);
    var that = this;

    $.each(this.reportNames, function () {
       if(reportCounter <= 2)
        $('<option>' + that.reportNames[reportCounter] + '</option>').appendTo($report_type);
        reportCounter = reportCounter + 2;
    });
    $('<option>' + this.reportNames[1].startMonth[counter] + '</option>').appendTo($start_month);

    $('<option>' + this.reportNames[1].endDate[counter] + '</option>').appendTo($end_date);

    $('<option>' + this.reportNames[1].endMonth[counter] + '</option>').appendTo($end_month);

    counter++;
});
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.   Please always explain how your solution works and why it is a good idea for the benefit of future researchers.